# Prepositions in compound sentences

Tags: grammar, prepositions, compound-complex

Should I repeat the preposition in a compound sentence? Borrowing a line from "The Alchemist" as an example:

> He knew how to shear them and how to slaughter them

Can this sentence be written as follows as well?

> a) He knew how to shear them and slaughter them 
> b) He knew how to shear and slaughter them 
> c) He knew to shear them and slaughter them

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes to all three. But although the meaning might be the same, there is room for differences of nuance. The closer the two actions are to one another, the more easily the suggested omissions will fit the context and the text will read.

For example:
**He loved to steal a drink and a kiss** doesn't improve with the additional words.

But in the following:
**He knew how to handle them and how to how to get rid of them when they became an embarrassment**, the second **how to** serves to emphasise the latter action.

In short, it's a matter of judgement and context.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the quotation refers to sheep, which are both shorn and slaughtered, but not in the same context. You could even say "He knew both how to shear them and how to slaughter them".

(a) is possible.

(b) is not so good, because it sounds as though the actions were done one after the other, like *wash and dry* or *dust and polish.*

(c) is definitely wrong. *He knew to do X* means that he knew that it was necessary to do it, not that he knew the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but be reminded of the lyrics of the somewhat famous song by Kenny Roger's called the [Gambler](https://www.google.com/search?q=know%20when%20to%20hold%20them&source=hp&ei=xjT4YZD8DpqmptQP98Km6AM&iflsig=AHkkrS4AAAAAYfhC1kbB_MFTY6jNSJFK4bd1PwzGzMlJ&gs_ssp=eJzj4tVP1zc0TEmrNEjJszA2YPQSy87LL1coz0jNUyjJV8jIz0lRKMlIzQUA7j8MqQ&oq=know%20when%20to%20h&gs_lcp=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&sclient=gws-wiz#wptab=s:H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgVuLVT9c3NExJqzRIybMwfsRowS3w8sc9YSn9SWtOXmPU5OIKzsgvd80rySypFJLmYoOyBKX4uVB18uxi0ktJTUsszSmJL0lMsspOttLPLS3OTNYvSk3OL0rJzEuPT84pLS5JLbLKqSzKTC5exCqfnZqXV6lQlJ-eWlSsUJKRqpCemJuUk1qkAFEBAHyFfoefAAAA).  The entire lyrics are worth reading and understanding if you don't understand the references, but the words relevant to the original poster's questions describe an approach to playing the game of poker that is supposed to apply to life in general:

> You've got to know when to hold 'em
>
> Know when to fold 'em
>
> Know when to walk away
>
> And know when to run

Since the emphasis in the song is on having the right judgment and knowledge, the repetition of the verb and adverb help to keep the lines parallel and together.  Similarly, with the original three choices posted in the original question, what you repeat and what you omit can both tie things together or create a useful parallelism to tie them together in a different way.